# Authorize.net sandbox transactions API not working in live server

Tags: php, sandbox, authorize.net-cim

In Last 3 day `Authorize.net` sandbox API's not working in live server but its working fine in my localhost

live server and localhost server source code are same. still in live server its giving null response like below

```
AuthorizeNetCIM_Response Object
(
    [xml] => 
    [response] => 
)
```

Please help me with this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

after some research i found solution. that was about to cert.pem file(SSL cirtificate).

in curl request there is code that using cert.pem like below

```
curl_setopt($curl_request, CURLOPT_CAINFO, dirname(dirname(__FILE__)) . '/ssl/cert.pem');
```

i just simply download certificate file from http://curl.haxx.se/docs/caextract.html and replaced with current cert.pem file and its worked !!.